# method to call on application starts

Tags: spring-mvc

is there any method in spring mvc that execute when the application starts for the first time like in BaseClass in struts.I working on sessions on spring.I have set session variable in one method but that has been calling each time (eg:- when the page get refreshed).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spring will execute the constructors of your beans when the application is starting, you can also annotate a method on a bean with `@PostConstruct` so it will be invoked after the bean is created this way the injected dependencies will already be available to you.

This can also be achieved in XML config by

```
<bean class="MyBean" init-method="start" />
```